# How to call a Method every 10 seconds with c# asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

Im stuck trying to call a method every 10 seconds, I read about timers and threads but the problem is that i do not know where to put the method to be fired, MVC projects have a Main?

```
    private async Task ActualizarPrecios()
      {
        Entities model = new Entities();
        var transaciones = model.Transacciones.Where(a => a.ESTADO == 
         true).ToList();
        string Url = ObtenerUrl(model);

        ApiForex.IniciarCliente();

        ProcesarRequest procesar = new ProcesarRequest();
        JObject divisas = await procesar.CargarJson(Url);

        foreach(Transacciones item in transaciones)
        {
          item.PRECIO_ACTUAL = (string)divisas["rates"][item.DIVISA] 
        ["rate"];
        }
        model.SaveChanges();
     }
```

The code that is to upload some columns of tables in the database. I dont know how to fire this method every x seconds

Comment: Please explain what the above code is trying to achieve.

Comment: If your app is hosted on Azure then you can use Azure Web Jobs. Otherwise maybe it makes sense to use some third-party libs like Hangfire or Quartz. But if only one method should be called periodically then it's possible to run your routine from `Global.asax` or `Startup.cs`.

Comment: Thanks that is what Im looking for!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use JavaScript to achieve this.

At the bottom of your View file (*.cshtml) add this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var interval = 10000; 
 setInterval(function() { Update() }, interval);

 function Update(){
     $.get("/[ControllerName]/ActualizarPrecios", function(){
         alert( "Load was performed.")}
     );
 } 
</script>
```

Explanation:

`<script type="text/javascript">`

> This is HTML denodes you are writing scripts in the JavaScript language

`var interval = 10000; 
 setInterval(function() { Update() }, interval);`

> Sets the interval to 10 seconds (in milliseconds)
>
> Then uses the JavaScript function for repeating executions on an interval see more on [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

```
function Update(){
     $.get("/[ControllerName]/ActualizarPrecios", function(){
         alert( "Load was performed.")}
     );
 }
```

> This function uses [Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_get.asp) in [jQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_syntax.asp) to call an API. Which exists in your controller. You haven't shared your controller name so replace the code accordingly, the method looks like a get method to me however it is `post`then change `$.get` to `$.post`. The function after the url path is executed on callback to your request. For now, to make it clear during testing it is running the line `alert( "Load was performed.")` which will pop up a dialog box in your browser; if you want to write something out to the html after running the request you can do that here.

*Note jQuery is included out the box in MVC C# projects. In your `\shared\_Layout.cshtml` file you'll see it reference in a section at the bottom of the page.

Comment: That will run it every 10 seconds **for every web browser tab that has that page loaded**. That may, or may not, be what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to investigate scheduling APIs and third party tools. Hangfire (https://www.hangfire.io/) is one that I have used successfully

Comment: Since Hangfire needs storage, it can be simplified by using Memory Storage: https://github.com/perrich/Hangfire.MemoryStorage

Answer (score 0):

1) If your application is going to host on Server or virtual machine (VM) then you can create window service and register service on the same.

Url : https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-Windows-Service-that-runs-periodically-and-once-a-day-at-specific-time-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

2) If your application is going to host on Azure pass then you can use Azure web jobs for the same.
Url : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create